# EF Core conditional (add) includes to an IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

In EF6 I was used to doing this:

```
var orders = GetAllEntities().Include(x => x.Contact.User);
if (includeProducts)
{
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders.Select(y => y.RentStockOrders));
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders.Select(y => y.Product));
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders.Select(y => y.Currency));
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders.Select(y => y.Coupons));
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.AdditionalCosts);
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.Partner);
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.OrderCoupons.Select(y => y.Coupon.Partner));
    if (includeStock)
    {
        orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders.Select(y => y.RentStockOrders.Select(z => z.Stock)));
    }
}
if (includeInvoices)
{
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.Invoices.Select(y => y.Attachments));
}
```

In EF Core it is not possible to override `IQueryable` because it is more 'typesafe'

The first line returns a `IIncludableQueryable<Order, User>`, so when I would do the second Include, it wants to make it something different, for example `IIncludableQueryable<Ordr,User,ProductOrder>`

I mostly have a `GetByIdWithCrudRelations` which contains a set of bools to choose what to include and what not. sometimes it has only two, but in this case it has 8, which means it can have a lot of different outcomes if I would need to if-else everything.

Anyone got a clever solution for this?

Comment: The second include is `Include` or `ThenInclude`? Looks like you are doing `ThenInclude` which takes the property specified earlier.

Comment: This seems like one of those architecture decision that a company would make once and then regret supporting it.  Handling thing that include several entities would be ugly, and what and dependent on the order you include things.

Comment: @johnny5 I agree that this is might not be the best architecture design but it isn't the most bad one either imo, get the data you want and don't pull more then needed from the db, don't write x different methods and don't use lazy loading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use exactly the same pattern. Just start with `IQueryable<T>` variable (note that `IIncludableQueryable<T, P>` is still `IQueryable<T>` with additional `ThenInclude` support) and use `ThenInclude` instead of nested `Select`s:

```
IQueryable<Order> orders = GetAllEntities().Include(x => x.Contact.User);
// or var orders = GetAllEntities().Include(x => x.Contact.User).AsQueryable();
if (includeProducts)
{
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.RentStockOrders);
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.Product);
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.Currency);
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.Coupons);
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.AdditionalCosts);
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.Partner);
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.OrderCoupons).ThenInclude(y => y.Coupon.Partner);
    if (includeStock)
    {
        orders = orders.Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.RentStockOrders).ThenInclude(z => z.Stock);
    }
}
if (includeInvoices)
{
    orders = orders.Include(x => x.Invoices).ThenInclude(y => y.Attachments);
}
```

Note that since `ThenInclude` chain is not nested, there is no need of different variable names `x`, `y`, `z` etc. - single `x` or similar would do the same.

Also since `Include` is restarting the include chain from the root, the non conditional assignments like `orders = orders.Include(...)` can be combined, e.g.

```
orders = orders
    .Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.RentStockOrders)
    .Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.Product)
    .Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.Currency)
    .Include(x => x.ProductOrders).ThenInclude(y => y.Coupons)
    .Include(x => x.AdditionalCosts)
    .Include(x => x.Partner)
    .Include(x => x.OrderCoupons).ThenInclude(y => y.Coupon.Partner);
```

Comment: haha, I always try to avoid `var`, and for once I don't I get into trouble *faceslap*

Comment: in this case, how can I sort the information? for exemple I try `.Include(x => x.ProductOrders.OrderBy(po => po.RentStockOrders)).ThenInclude(y => y.RentStockOrders)`but I receive an InvalidOperationException

Comment: @lebarillier You can't sort/filter Includes in EF6 either. The only allowed LINQ operator inside  `Include` was `Select`.

Comment: so it's no solution, to sort the ProductOrders? even in ef core? and actually, I must return an `IIncludableQueryable`

Comment: @lebarillier Negative. AFAIK there are plans for adding [filtered includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan#filtered-include) in v5.0, but not ordered. In general collection navigation properties are unordered, you should really do the ordering in the UI, or in memory after materializing the query.

Answer (score -1):

*Edit:  Since posting, Gert Arnold informed me that my answer isn't correct.  In that the 'Filtered Includes' method I mentioned here, doesn't actually determine which navigation properties are to be included, and will just reduce the number of items pulled from the database.  See Gert Arnold's comment below.

---

You can also place a Where clause within an .Include() through a feature called 'Filtered Includes'.

Such as:

> order.Include(x => x.ProductOrders.Where(w => includeStock == true))

There are a few stipulations, so please see the following for Documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't answer the question. There's far more that can be told about `Include`. It's all off-topic.

Comment: @GertArnold maybe I'm not understanding.  Couldn't the OP have all their Includes in one place, instead of interspersed within multitudinous if-else clauses, and then handle the conditional code within the .Include Where Clause of each specific Include.  I mean, it is still using conditional logic, but this way it looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: Also, I should note that Ivan Stoev handled the question covering the similarity of the IIncludableQuery return values.

Comment: The if/else clauses determine *which* navigation properties are to be included. Filtered includes don't do that. A filtered include only reduces the number of items that is pulled from the database. I.e. the logic for `includeInvoices` can only be coded by conditionally adding an Include, not by filtering an Include.